# Find the $x$ values of any points on the curve $y=\frac{3x}{\sqrt{5x-1}}$ where the tangent line is horizontal

Tags: derivatives

I am currently working through this problem. My plan is to find the derivative function and then set $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to $0$ and determine at what values of $x$ the function equals $y$.

Step one

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(5x-1)^{1/2} \times 3 -3x \times \frac{1}{2}(5x-1)^{-1/2}\times5}{5x-1}$$

Step two

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(5x-1)^{1/2} \times 3}{5x-1} - \frac{15x^2}{2(5x-1)^{3/2}}$$

Step three

$$\frac{(5x-1)^{1/2}\times 3\times (5x-1)^{1/2}\times 2}{2(5x-1)^{3/2}} - \frac{15x^2}{2(5x-1)^{3/2}} $$

Step four

$$\frac{6(5x-1)^{3/2}-15x^2}{2(5x-1)^{3/2}}$$

Don't really know where to go from here or if my strategy is right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
\frac{dy}{dx} & = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{3x}{\sqrt{5x-1}} \\
 & = \left(\frac{d}{dx}3x\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{5x-1}}+\left(\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{\sqrt{5x-1}}\right)3x\\
&=\frac{3}{\sqrt{5x-1}}+\left(\frac{d}{dx}\left(5x-1\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)3x\\
&=\frac{3}{\sqrt{5x-1}}+\left(-\frac{1}{2(5x-1)^{3/2}}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(5x-1)\right)3x\\
&=\frac{3}{\sqrt{5x-1}}-\frac{15x}{2(5x-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\\
&=\frac{6(5x-1)}{2(5x-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}-\frac{15x}{2(5x-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\\
&=\frac{15x-6}{2(5x-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
This expression is equal to zero when $x=\displaystyle\frac{2}{5}$.

Comment: Thanks. How did you get from the last step to $x={2/5}$?

Comment: @user183974 The numerator, $15x-6$, must be equal to zero, so $x=2/5$.